# How to get difference of two rows in same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row

I have to find the difference in the value of a single column of table as current row value-previous row value for some 'n' number of rows in one column and also I don't have ID to use as reference for increment

date:    box_count :       total_no_of_boxes_used

```
1/12/12 2   2
2/12/12 8   6
3/12/12 14  6
```

I have box_count column  and I am trying to get total_no_of_boxes_used column.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your `date` is sequential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your records are sequential by date.....

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a4e/1)

Query:

```
select a.date, a.bc, case when (a.bc-b.bc) is null then a.bc else a.bc-b.bc end tot
from tt a
left join 
tt b
on a.date > b.date
group by b.date
;
```

Results:

```
DATE                            BC      TOT
December, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000     2   2
December, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000     8   6
December, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000     14  6
December, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000     23  9
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal thanks. But I am trying to see if yours is faster and more logical (from first look it is). Since I find `case` is rather not so sharp at times.. If so I will give you +2 :D

Comment: I thing `JOIN` will be faster than the correlated subquery, unless the MySQL optimizer is smart enaugh.

Comment: Yeah true, the two `explain plan` shows that.. Well anyway OP has many choices. More the merrier.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is using a correlated subquery like so:

```
SELECT
  t1.`date`,
  t1.box_count,
  t1.box_count -
  IFNULL((SELECT t2.box_count
          FROM table1 t2
          WHERE t2.`date` < t1.`date`
          ORDER BY t2.`date` DESC
          LIMIT 1), 
        0 ) AS total_no_of_boxes_used
FROM table1 t1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b118/4)

This will give you:

```
|                            DATE | BOX_COUNT | TOTAL_NO_OF_BOXES_USED |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  January, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000 |         2 |                      2 |
| February, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000 |         8 |                      6 |
|    March, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000 |        14 |                      6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT date, 
       (box_count - @diff) total_no_of_boxes_used, 
       (@diff:=box_count) box_count
FROM table1, (SELECT @diff:=0) A;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbe3f/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
|                            DATE | TOTAL_NO_OF_BOXES_USED | BOX_COUNT |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  January, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000 |                      2 |         2 |
| February, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000 |                      6 |         8 |
|    March, 12 2012 00:00:00+0000 |                      6 |        14 |
```